# Not getting View for "cell.selectedBackgroundView"

Tags: iphone, tableview

I am trying to change my cell image when i click on it. I use the code like below :

```
cell.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];

cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:162.0/255.0 green:13.0/255.0 blue:20.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
cell.textLabel.text = [channelCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UIImage * backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topAndBottomRow.png"];
UIImage * selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topAndBottomRowSelected.png"];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIImage *indicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"indicator.png"];
cell.accessoryView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:indicatorImage] autorelease];

cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).image = backgroundImage;
((UIImageView *)cell.selectedBackgroundView).image = selectionBackground;
```

Can any one help me out for this issue?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't typecast to `UIImageView`. Allocate another `UIImageView` object, set its image and then assign `UIImageView` to `cell.backgroundView` or `cell.selectedBackgroundView`

Comment: Thank u for ur reply. I tried in that way also still i am not getting.

Comment: Hey i got it. I made mistake some where else. Thanks for replying me.

Comment: Hey sny, can you please tell me how you get it? In my tableview, I want to use both cell.backgroundView or cell.selectedBackgroundView with different image, its not working for me. it takes cell.backgroundView but it not takes cell.selectedBackgroundView when I select a row in table.